# Using wildcard in Xpath with attributes

Tags: xpath

Here is my html contents that I am trying to parse with XPath

```
<td class="text1">Content</td>
<td class="text2">Content</td>
<td class="text2">Content</td>
```

I want to select the td elements using the class attribute but as obvious, the value for this attribute is different for each element.I have tried:

```
//td[starts-with(@class,'text')]
```

but this approach is not working.What could be the correct way?

Comment: Works for me. What XPath processor are you using? Does `//td` select all table cells? You could have a namespace issue.

Answer (score 16):

You can use "contains":

```
//td[contains(@class, 'text')]
```